# How fix react-native global.BlobBuilder error?

Tags: react-native

I have reloaded my mac and get that error: [image: blobbuilder]

After dismissed that:
[image: rcteventeemitter]

react@16.3.2

react-native@0.55.4

babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0

[package.json](https://gist.github.com/Dictory/e05b9b2161a6b4213b36cbd37d33d499)

Can you tell me what can I do and what is this error?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/251

Comment: @JordanDaniels that doesnt help me =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was long road to fix this issue, short long story:
Unlink all packages, uninstall pods, upgrade react-native by [react-native-git-upgrade](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade) and [rn-diff](https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff), check major changes in other rn-packages, use [new pods](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies) for rn > 0.47, link packages and install pods.

If you get stuck with .xcodeproj or your xcode crash when you open project - reset your .xcodeproj [by rn-diff](https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff/blob/rn-0.55.4/RnDiffApp/ios/RnDiffApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj) (or clear project) and start again.

use [kin](https://github.com/Karumi/Kin) for lint xcode project

I think that issue was because i missed new pods